# HTML does not render on props change in Child Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, parent-child, render

I am building a backend in react. Where I show a user list, on click of a user need to show the user detail. So basically I have created a child component (user-detail.jsx) which has the user details html and included it in the parent (users.jsx). Would like to inform that child component is a functional component. It allows the admin to de-activate a user. So when admin deactivates user it calls an action and dispatch success method. Everything is working fine till this point.

The issue is that in my child component, the changes are not getting detected. To verify I have tried to console messages in "componentWillReceiveProps". But it does not re-render the html as I need to hide the "De-activate" button and show the "Activate".

I have added the **minimal code** to explain the problem. Added the comments with **sequence number (1, 2,3, 4 ...13)** in front of each comment.

**NOTE: I have already seen similar questions on stack overflow. But I couldn't find any solution.**

```js
// 2. this is the first function been called when clicked on each user row

handleVideoDetailClick = (user) => (_event) => {
    /*
    * this.props.showUserDetail is a mapped action. defined in  user.actions.js
    */
    this.props.showUserDetail(user);
  }
  
  
  // 3. user.actions.js
  
  function showUserDetail(user) {
  return dispatch => {
    // 4. userService: it calls a service method which makes an api call and return back the response
    userService.getById(user.id)
      .then(
        result => {
          if (result.status === 1) {
            // 5. dispatches the success action.
            dispatch(success(result.data));
          } else {
            dispatch(failure(result.data));
            dispatch(alertActions.error(result.data));
          }
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
          dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
        }
      );
  };

  function success(data) { return { type: userConstants.SHOW_DETAIL, data } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.FAILURE, error } }
}


// 6. users.reducer.js

export function users(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ......
    ......
    ......
    case userConstants.SHOW_DETAIL:
      // 7. set the flagDetail button to true and it will show the child component on same page (user.jsx)
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.data.user,
        challenges: action.data.challenges,
        posts: action.data.posts,
        flagDetail: true
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}


// 8. On click of activate/ deactivate this function is been called in user-detail.jsx

handleDeactivateBtnClick() {
    const { user } = this.props
    this.props.deactivateUser({ id: user.id, isDeactivatedByUser: (user.isDeactivatedByUser ? 0 : 1) });
  }
  
  
 // 9. it calls a service method to activate/ deactivate button
 
 function deactivateUser(reqBody) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request());

    userService.deactivateUser(reqBody)
      .then(
        result => {
          if (result.status === 1) {
          // 10. dispatches the success action.
            dispatch(success(result.data));
          } else {
            dispatch(failure(result.data));
            dispatch(alertActions.error(result.data));
          }
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
          dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
        }
      );
  };

  function request() { return { type: userConstants.DEACTIVATE_REQUEST } }
  function success(data) { return { type: userConstants.DEACTIVATE_SUCCESS, data } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.DEACTIVATE_FAILURE, error } }
}

// 11. users.reducer.js

export function users(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ......
    ......
    ......
    case userConstants.DEACTIVATE_SUCCESS:
      let user = state.user
      console.log('befere ', user.isDeactivatedByUser)
      user.isDeactivatedByUser = user.isDeactivatedByUser ? 0 : 1
      // 12. It is working fine, till this point.
      console.log('after ', user.isDeactivatedByUser)
      
      return { ...state, loadingDeactivate: false, user: user };
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// 13. This is how the values are being fetched from the props in uder-detail.jsx

function mapState(state) {
  const { user, challenges, posts } = state.users;
  return { user, challenges, posts };
}

const actionCreators = {
  hideUserDetail: userActions.hideUserDetail,
  deactivateUser: userActions.deactivateUser,
};

export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(UserDetail);
```

```html
<!-- 1. users.jsx (parent component) -->

return (
        <tr key={index.toString()}>
          <td></td>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td onClick={this.handleVideoDetailClick(item)}>
            <div className='tdImage backgroundProp profile-round' style={{ background: `url("${commonConstants.thumbnailUrl}/${item.profilePic}")` }}>
            </div>
          </td>
          <!-- on click of this, it need to show the detail component -->
          <td onClick={this.handleVideoDetailClick(item)}>{item.username}</td>
          <td onClick={this.handleVideoDetailClick(item)}>{item.displayName}</td>
          <td>{item.email}</td>
          <td>{getDeviceTypeById(item.deviceType)}</td>
          <td><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
      
      
    <!-- 7. Here is the activate/ deactivate button child component -->
    
    const btnActivateDeactivate = user && user.isDeactivatedByUser ? (<button className="btnActivate user-disable" id="btnActivate" onClick={this.handleDeactivateBtnClick}><i className="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i><i className="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Activate</button>) : (<button className="btnDeactivate user-disable" id="btnDeactivate" onClick={this.handleDeactivateBtnClick}><i className="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Deactivate</button>)
```

Comment: Show us your code pls

Comment: Without the code, we can only take guesses.

Comment: It is divided in couple of files (component + action service + reducer + child component). Shall i add all ?

Comment: you can use the snippet

Comment: @Shen I have added the minimal code to explain the problem. Added the comments with  sequence number (1, 2,3, 4 ...13) in front of each comment. Please check and let me know if there is any other query.